# How to clean my client knowledge panel

Tags: seo, google, knowledge-graph, technical-seo

I have an SEO client who was in the Japanese adult industry, Which helps her appear in the Google Knowledge Panel. Now she is a Dj still Knowledge Panel showing her an adult actor, What I can do to help her with this.

Comment: You have to work on online reputation and getting more citations that her profession is changed. Google will sense it and improvise. Moreover fill a knowledge panel update form from here - https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/gethelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options would seem to be explained in the following Google help documents:

- [About knowledge panels](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9163198?hl=en-GB)
- [Update your Google knowledge panel](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534842)

Which states...

> If you are the subject of or official representative of an entity
> depicted in a knowledge panel, you can claim this panel and suggest
> changes. More information about these processes are available in the
> following articles:
>
> - [Get verified on Google](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534902)
> - [Update your Google knowledge panel](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534842)

Source: https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9163198?hl=en-GB

> To suggest changes to your entity's knowledge panel, follow the steps
> below:
>
> 1. Go to Google Search.
> 2. Sign in to the Google Account associated with the entity that you represent.
> 3. Check that your Web and app activity is turned on.
> 4. Search for your entity on Google and find its knowledge panel. Ensure that you see your entity’s title at the top of the knowledge
>    panel.
> 5. At the top of the knowledge panel, click **Suggest an edit** (or **Suggest edits** on mobile). If you don’t see this option, it is because either:
>
>    - You’re not signed in with the same account used to claim the knowledge panel, or
>    - Google doesn’t recognise your Google Account as a verified representative of the entity. Follow these steps to [get
>      verified](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534902),
>      or visit https://www.google.com/search/contributions/manage from a
>      verified account to add additional users to the account.
> 6. Click the information that you want to change. If you have multiple suggestions, submit feedback for each item separately.
> 7. In the response box that opens, write a short description that includes the following:
>
>    - Clearly state your suggested change.
>    - Explain why you believe that your suggestion should replace the existing content.
>    - If applicable, include any publicly accessible URLs that confirm your suggested changes.
> 8. Click Send.

Source: https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534842

Comment: I try "Suggest an edit" more than 4 times, and also advise the client to do the same. but still no improvement.
i also talk to Jason Barnard on Twitter according to his website blog, the sources of the information are open public portals like, wiki japan/IMDb